# Receiving variable sent by Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm still working through Camel and I have a question concerning the following use case:

I need to get some data from a url, in XML format, and send it to another URL.  One thing I do not understand is how to retrieve the data sent by Camel.  If I send some data by using `.to(http://someurl)` is this sent by post or get?  What is the variable name that I need to retrieve?

The following is the route I have configured:

```
from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&delay=0&period=60000")
    .to("http4://someurl")
    .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
                    map.add("xml", exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));

                    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

                    String responses = restTemplate.postForObject("http://someUrl", map,  String.class);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

see http://camel.apache.org/http4.html

> Camel will store the HTTP response from the external server on the OUT body.
>      All headers from the IN message will be copied to the OUT message, so headers are preserved during routing. 
>      Additionally Camel will add the HTTP response headers as well to the OUT message headers.
>
> Calling using GET or POST
>      The following algorithm is used to determine if either GET or POST HTTP method should be used:
>
> 1. Use method provided in header.
> 2. GET if query string is provided in header.
> 3. GET if endpoint is configured with a query string.
> 4. POST if there is data to send (body is not null).
> 5. GET otherwise.

POST example...response in OUT BODY

```
from("direct:start")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, 
        constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.POST))
    .to("http4://www.google.com")
    .to("log:results");
```

Comment: OK, this i understand, but in my example, i'm consuming content from web page (consuming XML), and i want to pass it to some URL. When i'm consuming it, i'm consuming content, not variable, so when i send it to another URL, i'm also send it as some content. My problem is - how to receive the content in Java controller, when i don't know what is the variable name, that i send from camel?

Comment: not sure I follow...if the message coming from Camel has XML in the Exchange Body, then that XML will be used as the HTTP POST body.  Alternatively, you can explicitly set values as Http header properties and use a GET instead...

Comment: OK, so from the begining. Firstly i download content of a web page, where is XML using http4. Secondly i want to push the content to a Java Web Service, where the content will be recived. How can i recive the message in Web Service sent by camel, if the message has no name, through which i can get it - like: `request.getParameters("variableName")` ?